# Laravel REST API "Status 404 Not Found"

Tags: php, api, http, laravel

Currently we have a Laravel Rest API system running inside a Linux Server running with Apache, PHP and a remote database which is a SQL Server. My superiors asked me to create the same system but instead using Windows, IIS, and PHP. Now I've followed all installation instructions in the net and even arrived at the laravel 5 screen page. Now when I transferred laravel files and installed it in windows it did not have any error in the process. I even imported my .htaccess config to IIS. However when I made a request to the API it is returning a http status 404 error.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

     RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you have to translate the htaccess to web.config or simple way, use [*heliconape*](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but I already did translate it to web.config in IIS.

Comment: you should post the config file then. htaccess is useless here.

Comment: added web.config file in the question